# Перевод SQL-запроса в JPQL

Tags: orm, eclipselink

Пытаюсь переписать нативный SQL-запрос в JPQL EclipseLink.
Запрос ищет сервисный центр с самой низкой средней зарплатой у сотрудников.

```
select center_id from 
(select center_id, avg(salary) as avg_salary from EMPLOYEE group by center_id) 
where avg_salary = 
(select min(avg_salary) from (select center_id, avg(salary) as avg_salary 
from EMPLOYEE group by center_id))
```

Вот моя попытка перевести его в JPQL. В чем моя ошибка?

```
select c from (select e.center.name as c, avg(e.salary) as avg_salary 
from Employee e group by e.center.name) 
where avg_salary = (select min(avg_salary) 
from (select e.center.name as c, avg(e.salary) as avg_salary 
from Employee e group by e.center.name))
```

Все что мне пока удалось перевести в JPQL, это просто узнать минимальную среднюю зарплату у каждого центра

```
select e.center.name as c, avg(e.salary) as avg_salary 
from Employee e group by e.center.name
```

Comment: JPQL гораздо скромнее полноценного SQL. Вполне может быть что такая задача ему не по зубам. И ещё. Сложные длинные запросы в одну строку - "невкусно ни мене, ни тебе, никому".

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Поправил оформление.

Comment: Вообще JPA не поддерживает под-запросы в from, но eclipse в частности, пишут, поддерживает. Может надо получать `алияс-для-ентити.свойство` из под-запроса, а не просто `c`?